# assigning value in column C based on repetead date in column B

Tags: r

I have a dataset with dates of implementation.

```
ID     Date_implemented

345    2020-01-01
2      2020-01-01
67     2020-01-02
380    2020-01-02
9      2020-01-02
176    2020-01-03
```

I want to create a new column and assign a binary c(1,-1) on every different date. For example my dataset would look like this:

```
ID     Date              C

345    2020-01-01        1
2      2020-01-01        1
67     2020-01-02        -1
380    2020-01-02        -1
9      2020-01-02        -1
176    2020-01-03        1
```

I have tried with

```
rep(c(1,-1),length.out=length(Date)
```

but it does not give me the results above but rather alternates each row between 1 and -1.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution based in the tidyverse could look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(C = if_else(as.double(str_sub(Date_implemented, -1)) %% 2 == 0, -1, 1))

#      ID Date_implemented     C
#   <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>
# 1   345 2020-01-01           1
# 2     2 2020-01-01           1
# 3    67 2020-01-02          -1
# 4   380 2020-01-02          -1
# 5     9 2020-01-02          -1
# 6   176 2020-01-03           1
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(345, 2, 67, 380, 9, 176), Date_implemented = c("2020-01-01", 
"2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: It is almost always wrong to use `df$` within a dplyr pipe (unless you are bringing in external data). While it doesn't warn or error here, it will break if there are any changes to the data before this `mutate` call (some will be errors, often just corrupted data).

Comment: Thank you very much @r2evans. I made an unfortunate mistake. I have edited my solution and replaced ```df$``` with ```.$```.

Comment: It's a common mistake. The risk is data corruption (inaccurate calculations), and that risk is doubled-down because often it comes with no warnings or errors. In your case, remove the `.$`, and let it work the way `dplyr` is intended to work, just `Date_implemented`.

Comment: @r2evans: Of course! Yet another edit made. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Base R option:

```r
grp <- cumsum(c(TRUE, (dat$Date_implemented[-1] != dat$Date_implemented[-nrow(dat)])))
grp
# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3
dat$C <- ifelse(grp %% 2 == 1, 1, -1)
dat
#    ID Date_implemented  C
# 1 345       2020-01-01  1
# 2   2       2020-01-01  1
# 3  67       2020-01-02 -1
# 4 380       2020-01-02 -1
# 5   9       2020-01-02 -1
# 6 176       2020-01-03  1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep with `rep()` function, I believe this will give what you want. The `df$Date` refers to your Date column.

```
rep(rep(c(1,-1), length.out = length(unique(df$Date))), times = table(df$Date))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag` to compare the current value to the previous value.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(c = ifelse(dates == lag(dates), 1, -1))
```

Comment: It does what I want but it skips the first row of the dataset. Any ides how to fix this?

Comment: When I run that code locally, the new columns is `NA,1,-1,1,1,-1`, which is not what the OP suggested (`1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1`), even ignoring the first `NA`.