# Add new column with values looping through a vector every time the value of a reference column change

Tags: r

My data:

```
ID  B

1   1
2   1
3  -1
4  -1
5  -1
6   1
7   1
```

I would like to create a column C that the value loops through c(1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5) when the value of column B is 1 and loops through c(-1.0, -1.5, -2.0, -2.5)  when the value of column B is -1. The values should reset every time the value of column B changes.

The outcome would look like this:

```
ID  B   C

1   1   1.0
2   1   1.5
3  -1   -1.0
4  -1   -1.5
5  -1   -2.0
6   1   1.0
7   1   1.5
8   1   2.0
```

I tried using as a reference an older question I posted [assigning value in column C based on repetead date in column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65971298/assigning-value-in-column-c-based-on-repetead-date-in-column-b) but I cannot make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R one-liner with `ave`.

```
df1$C <- ave(df1$B, cumsum(c(0, diff(df1$B)) != 0), FUN = function(x) x*seq(1, by = 0.5, length.out = length(x)))

df1
#  ID  B    C
#1  1  1  1.0
#2  2  1  1.5
#3  3 -1 -1.0
#4  4 -1 -1.5
#5  5 -1 -2.0
#6  6  1  1.0
#7  7  1  1.5
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
ID  B
1   1
2   1
3  -1
4  -1
5  -1
6   1
7   1
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr/data.table`, create a grouping column based on `rleid` on the 'B' column and then create the `seq`uence based on it

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
   group_by(grp = rleid(B)) %>%
   mutate(C = B *seq(1, by = 0.5, length.out = n())) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#     ID     B     C
#  <int> <int> <dbl>
#1     1     1   1  
#2     2     1   1.5
#3     3    -1  -1  
#4     4    -1  -1.5
#5     5    -1  -2  
#6     6     1   1  
#7     7     1   1.5
```

---

In `base R`, we could use `rle`

```
df1$C <-  with(df1, B * unlist(sapply(rle(B)$lengths,
       function(x) seq(1, by = 0.5, length.out = x))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:7, B = c(1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```